# How do you link local variables to other functions without having to use global variables?

Tags: javascript

How do I link up the 3 functions below so I can have `mathFormula` output an answer?

HTML text:

```html
<div id = "rowContainer"></div>
```

JavaScript text:

```js
function mathFormula(x, y) {
    return x * y;
}

const mainDiv = document.getElementById("rowContainer"); 

function newRow() {
    const input1 = document.createElement("input");
    mainDiv.appendChild(input1);
    const input2 = document.createElement("input");
    mainDiv.appendChild(input2);
    const result = document.createElement("div");
    mainDiv.appendChild(result);
}

mainDiv('keyup', function() {
    const a = input1.value; 
    const b = input2.value; 
    const sum = mathFormula(a,b); 
    result.textContent = sum; 
})
```

Comment: With an IIFE around your whole code, or with ES modules

Comment: What is `const input1 = input1;` supposed to mean? How can you initialize a variable to itself?

Comment: `I want to attach my mathformula function to the local variables inside the newRow function` but there are no local variables inside that function. Also what do you mean "attach"?

Comment: you want to multiply inputs  inside `newRow()`?

Comment: Yes, I want to multiply the two inputs named input 1 and 2 to produce an answer using the math formula function that holds my equation or x * y.  (INPUT1 * INPUT2 = RESULT)

Comment: The issue that **I** see is `const a = input1.value;` in the anonymous keyup handler in mainDiv. `input1` is declared in `newRow()` so is not visible outside of that function; the mainDiv function can't access input1 or input2. Many things are unclear in your question — `newRow()` isn't called anywhere, if called would newRow be called multiple times to keep adding rows? Possibly — If your `'keyup', function()` accepts the event parameter: `'keyup', function(e) {` you can use [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to find the field(s) you care about.

Comment: I am not being funny here, the question that I asked is simple, "How do I link up these 3 functions so I can have math formula output an answer?  The question I am asking is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only need 2 functions in this case.`newRow()`&`mathFormula`.
creating 3 `inputs` instead of one being a div.
appending all inputs inside our `rowContainer`.all at once, no need to do them separately.
then i am listening to a click on my button which i created inside html.
so,when we click the button.inside there i am calling our `mathFormula` function & passing the input1 & input2.

`let multiply=mathFormula(input1,input2)` which sends the these two inputs to mathFormula as object still.those inputs are then assigned to x,y.
then i am saying `x = x.value` & `y =y .value` then returns a single value of `x*y` which gets stored in the `multiply` variable. because we said.

`let multiply=mathFormula(input1,input2)` putting that value inside result input.

i hope it helps you.you can ask if you have any doubts

```js
const mainDiv = document.getElementById("rowContainer");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

function mathFormula(x, y) {
  x=x.value;
  y=y.value
  return x * y;
}
newRow(); /*-----Calling the newRow() rightAway*/
function newRow() {
  const input1 = document.createElement("input");
  const input2 = document.createElement("input");
  const result = document.createElement("input");
  mainDiv.append(input1, input2, result);
  btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  let multiply=mathFormula(input1,input2)
  result.value=multiply;
  })
  
}
```

```html
<div id="rowContainer"></div>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Functions can see variables in their containing scope, so the keyup listener, *if defined inside the newRow function*, captures the context of input elements.

The other thing to notice is that the listener is ambiguous unless attached to a specific row (capturing in scope that row's inputs).  The snippet below adds an extra div to hold the row, and attaches the listener at the row-div level.

```js
const mainDiv = document.getElementById('maindiv');

function mathFormula(x, y) {
  return x * y;
}

function addRow() {
  const rowDiv = document.createElement("div");
  mainDiv.appendChild(rowDiv);
  
  const input1 = document.createElement("input");
  rowDiv.appendChild(input1);

  const input2 = document.createElement("input");
  rowDiv.appendChild(input2);

  const result = document.createElement("div");
  rowDiv.appendChild(result);
  
  rowDiv.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    const a = input1.value;
    const b = input2.value;
    result.textContent = mathFormula(a, b);
  })
}

addRow()
addRow()
```

```html
<div id="maindiv">
</div>
```